# Bootstrap carousel - align <video> vertically middle of the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

Could you please take a look at my code?

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-3qaqj0lc6sV/qpzrc1N5DC6i1VRn/HyX4qdPaiEFbn54VjQBEU341pvjz7Dv3n6P" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-SI27wrMjH3ZZ89r4o+fGIJtnzkAnFs3E4qz9DIYioCQ5l9Rd/7UAa8DHcaL8jkWt" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="//via.placeholder.com/787x787" alt="First slide">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <video id="product-image-BMW©Tailpipe©Trim-0" class="d-block w-100" width="100%" controls="" preload="auto" muted="" autoplay="">
          <source src="https://youtu.be/vjhbm67KW1U?list=PLzgoLd4TRmNrR9m-RwfMtRM8qud3t7kjp" type="video/mp4">
          <source src="https://youtu.be/vjhbm67KW1U?list=PLzgoLd4TRmNrR9m-RwfMtRM8qud3t7kjp" type="video/webm">
        </video>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="//via.placeholder.com/787x787" alt="Third slide">
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h2>Description</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**I need to align this `<video>` vertically middle of the div (consider height of the image div)**.

Please note: *The parent div (carousel-item) shouldn't have a fixed height, because it is responsive.*

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vishnuprasadps/13dnbm0v/)

Comment: what do you mean by vertically middle of the div????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Bootstrap 4 alignment classes and `translateY` with `margin-top` in a custom CSS spinet, plus adding to `w-100` to `<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">` resulted into this:

```css
.carousel-item video {
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin-top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-3qaqj0lc6sV/qpzrc1N5DC6i1VRn/HyX4qdPaiEFbn54VjQBEU341pvjz7Dv3n6P" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-SI27wrMjH3ZZ89r4o+fGIJtnzkAnFs3E4qz9DIYioCQ5l9Rd/7UAa8DHcaL8jkWt" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 d-flex align-items-center">
      <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide w-100" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="//via.placeholder.com/787x787" alt="First slide">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <video id="product-image-BMW©Tailpipe©Trim-0" class="d-block w-100" controls="" preload="auto" muted="" autoplay="">
          <source src="https://youtu.be/vjhbm67KW1U?list=PLzgoLd4TRmNrR9m-RwfMtRM8qud3t7kjp" type="video/mp4">
          <source src="https://youtu.be/vjhbm67KW1U?list=PLzgoLd4TRmNrR9m-RwfMtRM8qud3t7kjp" type="video/webm">
        </video>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="//via.placeholder.com/787x787" alt="Third slide">
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 d-flex align-items-center">
    <div>
      <h2>Description</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @vishnu add the proper Bootstrap classes too.

Comment: This works..! but now facing another issue, <video> have different aspect ratio in this scenario.. so the exact position of `transform` & `margin-top` is unpredictable.

Comment: @vishnu What you are saying happens to you does not happen in my snippet (try it out) so it must be missing some details (classes).

Comment: Apologies, it is little bit difficult to reproduce the same code here. I added a solution to Snippet and the credit goes to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here you needs to add class `align-items-center` along with `row`

and `d-flex align-items-center` this 2 classes along with `carousel-inner`.

Hope this will help you.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-3qaqj0lc6sV/qpzrc1N5DC6i1VRn/HyX4qdPaiEFbn54VjQBEU341pvjz7Dv3n6P" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-SI27wrMjH3ZZ89r4o+fGIJtnzkAnFs3E4qz9DIYioCQ5l9Rd/7UAa8DHcaL8jkWt" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner d-flex align-items-center">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="//via.placeholder.com/787x787" alt="First slide">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <video id="product-image-BMW©Tailpipe©Trim-0" class="d-block w-100" width="100%" controls="" preload="auto" muted="" autoplay="">
          <source src="https://youtu.be/vjhbm67KW1U?list=PLzgoLd4TRmNrR9m-RwfMtRM8qud3t7kjp" type="video/mp4">
          <source src="https://youtu.be/vjhbm67KW1U?list=PLzgoLd4TRmNrR9m-RwfMtRM8qud3t7kjp" type="video/webm">
        </video>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="//via.placeholder.com/787x787" alt="Third slide">
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h2>Description</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: still have the issue.. see "Full page" mode, <video> not vertically center of the image div height.

Comment: @vishnu it will depends on your content. else you need to give a fixed height.

Comment: @vishnu look i updated the answer. you will notice.

Comment: @vishnu Does this answer helpful to you?

Comment: Checking with your answer, there is some other custom div & classes in master project, so I'll let you know once it is complete.

Answer (score 1):

This can definitely best be handled by flexbox, which newer versions of Bootstrap support.

I believe the correct syntax would be `class="d-flex justify-content-center"` for your element. If you'd like to read more into the specifics of the different flexbox-enabled Bootstrap syntax, I'd check out the [W3Schools Guide](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_flex.asp)

Here's a very good article serving as a "[Complete Guide to Flexboxes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#flexbox-background)", which is definitely worth the read for anyone doing web development (particularly mobile development, where dynamic or reactive styling is important)

Comment: Ah, apologies. This class actually needs to be set on the parent of the item, so in this case a <div></div> tag surrounding the video element.

Comment: No problem.. keep happy coding !

Answer (score 1):

Please check this may be helpful. I use `align-items-center` in row.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-3qaqj0lc6sV/qpzrc1N5DC6i1VRn/HyX4qdPaiEFbn54VjQBEU341pvjz7Dv3n6P" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-SI27wrMjH3ZZ89r4o+fGIJtnzkAnFs3E4qz9DIYioCQ5l9Rd/7UAa8DHcaL8jkWt" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="//via.placeholder.com/787x787" alt="First slide">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <video id="product-image-BMW©Tailpipe©Trim-0" class="d-block w-100" width="100%" controls="" preload="auto" muted="" autoplay="">
          <source src="https://youtu.be/vjhbm67KW1U?list=PLzgoLd4TRmNrR9m-RwfMtRM8qud3t7kjp" type="video/mp4">
          <source src="https://youtu.be/vjhbm67KW1U?list=PLzgoLd4TRmNrR9m-RwfMtRM8qud3t7kjp" type="video/webm">
        </video>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="//via.placeholder.com/787x787" alt="Third slide">
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h2>Description</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: still have the issue.. see "Full page" mode, <video> not vertically center of the image div height. :(

Answer (score 1):

**Using this solution:**

In my case, `<video>` aspect ratio may vary depending on the product item. So I added height for `carousel item` using jQuery, "height would be calculated from its width." Then, it is easier to position `<video>` vertically middle if the div!

```js
var cw = $('.carousel-item').width();
$('.carousel-item').css({
  'height': cw + 'px'
});
```

```css
video {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-3qaqj0lc6sV/qpzrc1N5DC6i1VRn/HyX4qdPaiEFbn54VjQBEU341pvjz7Dv3n6P" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-SI27wrMjH3ZZ89r4o+fGIJtnzkAnFs3E4qz9DIYioCQ5l9Rd/7UAa8DHcaL8jkWt" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="//via.placeholder.com/787x787" alt="First slide">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <video id="product-image-BMW©Tailpipe©Trim-0" class="d-block w-100" width="100%" controls="" preload="auto" muted="" autoplay="">
          <source src="https://youtu.be/vjhbm67KW1U?list=PLzgoLd4TRmNrR9m-RwfMtRM8qud3t7kjp" type="video/mp4">
          <source src="https://youtu.be/vjhbm67KW1U?list=PLzgoLd4TRmNrR9m-RwfMtRM8qud3t7kjp" type="video/webm">
        </video>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="//via.placeholder.com/787x787" alt="Third slide">
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h2>Description</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```